# Circular dependency?

Tags: clojure, luminus

I set up a basic luminus template with postgres. I want to be able to add new users and authenticate them, following an example from Ch.6 p.168 in this book: https://pragprog.com/titles/dswdcloj3/web-development-with-clojure-third-edition/

I had issues, so I started over with a new project to just try to get through this part.

I created a new luminus project, I created the database table, and I updated the project.clj file. I was able to migrate okay, but then I added an auth.clj file, and then went to restart with lein run, and now I get this error:

```
    Assert failed: circular dependency
    (not (depends? graph dep x))
```

I'm not sure what's going on, because my dependencies are the exact same as the source code, and I'm a total beginner.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I guess you'd need to show the namespace declarations.

Comment: ^^^ Please edit the question to add a list of files and the `(ns ...)` form in each.  And include all source code you added/changed in the example.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I double checked the (ns ...) parts i had written, and I had a typo in my auth.clj file. Now it works! For whatever reason, I panicked and didn't even think to check there for an error, but now I know.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Svante's hint, I double checked my namespace in the auth.clj file, and it turns out I just had a simple typo with the namespaces. When I got the error, I had panicked and didn't think to check that part. I fixed the typo and now lein run works! Thanks.